# Simple use of boost::regex match groups

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I want to use `boost::regex` to change the format of a bunch of dates on the format `19991231235959` to this format `1999-12-31_23:59:59` like this:

```
YYYYMMDDhhmmss --> YYYY-MM-DD_hh:mm:ss
19991231235959 --> 1999-12-31_23:59:59
```

I use this

```
std::string input = "19991231235959";
boost::regex regex("^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})");
std::string format = "\\1-\\2-\\3_\\4:\\5:\\6";
std::string output = boost::regex_replace(input, regex, format);
```

which works but is there a way to get rid of the repetitions `([0-9]{2})` in `regex`construction and keep the match groups?

Comment: Do you really really need regex for this?

Comment: Also, if you set `regex_constants::escape_in_lists`, you can use `\\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Maybe regex is not the best solution; I guess it is a bit of an exercise. The reason I considered regex in the first place is that the `regex` and `format` strings can be read from configuration.

Comment: I like the `\\d` suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your input data. If you have a 14 digit timestamp at the beginning of **every** input line you could use:

```
boost::regex regex("^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)");
```

Comment: This is certainly cuter but there is still the repetition `(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)` I am thinking about something like this `(....)(..){5}`

Comment: I.e. for numbers only `^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2}){5}`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar. One thing I like to do is name my capture groups though.

```
boost::regex regex("\\D*(?<YYYY>\\d{4})\\D*(?<MM>\\d{2})\\D*(?<DD>\\d{2})\\D*(?<hh>\d{2})\\D*(?<mm>\\d{2})\\D*(?<ss>\\d{2})");
```

That gives each group the same name as your format string. So you can do things like:

```
int year = lexical_cast<int>(what["YYYY"]);
int month = lexical_cast<int>(what["MM"]);
```

Using the built in character classes also helps. The above regex will match every one of these inputs:

```
20160922015227
2016 09 22 01 52 27
2016_09_22-01:52:27
```